# How object with members that are not specified in class be created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, oop, object

Picture below shows a MSDN reference of `RouteCollectionExtensions.Maproute` method.

The method have 1 parameter called **defaults** which is an **object** type.

[image: MSDN Reference]

Picture below shows a line of code (boxed) in a ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio which don't contain errors.

[image]

The code create a new object and passes it as argument into `MapRoute` method.
The object contains members namely `controller`, `action` and `id`.

However, the object is created from `System.Object` class. There is no such members specified in the System.Object class.

How the object be created since it do not have the class that have these members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various separate ideas you need to understand here.

Most importantly, there's the idea of an [*anonymous type*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). Look at this:

```
var x = new { Name = "Jon", Location = "Reading" };
```

That has created an instance of an *anonymous type*, and assigned the resulting reference to the variable `x`. At compile-time, the compiler will generate a type that actually has a name, but one you can't refer to.

Now in this case, `x` will be strongly typed to that "unnamed" type - but it would also be fine to use:

```
object x = new { Name = "Jon", Location = "Reading" };
```

After all, we're just creating an object, and *every* class type is compatible with `object`, in the same way that we could write:

```
object x = new StringBuilder();
```

The example code you've given is very similar, except that it's using the value as an argument to a method call, instead of assigning it to a variable.

The `MapRoute` method uses reflection to determine the properties of the anonymous type and the values stored in the instance passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The objects created like this;

```
new { foo="bar", id=7 }
```

actually have a type, but it's one generated by the compiler. It's called an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). But it still has properties, and you could still use reflection to see those properties. Eg;

```
new { foo="bar"}.GetType().GetProperties()
```

would return an array with one PropertyInfo object in it, representing "foo".

In the `MapRoutes` method, the parameter is declared as `object`, but that means it can take *anything* at all. In this case, it's taking your anonymous object. So MVC uses reflection to tell what properties you've sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

It uses anonymous types, which is supported in c#.  The type is created by the compiler later.

See [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide) from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)